# Limit the number of rows allowed in a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, table

I would like to set a maximum number of rows on a PostgreSQL table. I want users to be able to delete and recreate rows if need be; but there should never be more than x rows in my table. Is there a way to add such a constraint to a table - or a workaround to achieve the same goal?

The purpose of this is to prevent people from adding too many new polygons in a table. I'm looking for either a general SQL solution or a PostGIS-related solution (based on geometry for example).

Comment: There does not seem to be a GIS component to your question.

Comment: You're right. I didn't give enough details in my question and thus the GIS part was unclear. I edited it.

Comment: I was not one of those that voted to close your question, and my expertise is not in this space, so I will not counter their votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a trigger that checks the number of records in your destination table when an INSERT is used.

The trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_number_of_row()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
BEGIN
    -- replace 100 by the number of rows you want
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM your_table) > 100
    THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'INSERT statement exceeding maximum number of rows for this table' 
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_number_of_row 
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_number_of_row();
```

Comment: I already have several triggers on my table, so I was wondering whether a shorter, built-in Postgre/PgAdmin solution existed. But maybe there isn't any. I'll wait a few days and accept your answer if nothing else comes up. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This will not work for several reasons.
Trigger should return (in case of no errors): RETURN NEW
Also this will not prevent to have different transactions each of those adding 100 lines. After the commits you will get N*100 lines where N are the parallel open transactions.

Answer (score -3):

In your PostgreSQL query you can add a limit value:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1 LIMIT 100
```

This should give you the first 100 rows of the table.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because the OP wants to limit how much rows a table contains, not how much rows a SELECT on this returns.